# MySQL Unique Index between three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-keys, unique-index

I have the schema of the following tables:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `depts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `deptName` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `deptUniq` (`deptName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sub_depts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dept_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subDeptName` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `subDeptNameUniq` (`subDeptName`),
  KEY `keyDept` (`dept_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `keyDept` FOREIGN KEY (`dept_id`) REFERENCES `depts` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `objects` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sub_depts_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `objName` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `objNameUniq` (`objName`),
  KEY `keySubDept` (`sub_depts_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `keySubDept` FOREIGN KEY (`sub_depts_id`) REFERENCES `sub_depts` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

relationship between tables sub_depts and depts many-to-one
relationship between tables objects and sub_depts many-to-one
relationship between tables objects and depts must be one-to-one

if the tables objects and depts was one table a simple UNIQUE index (objName, deptName) would work
but need to keep the three tables separate

*example data:*

```
depts
1 dept1
2 dept2

sub_depts
1 1  subDept1
2 1  subDept2
3 2  subDept3

objects
1 1 obj1
```

*after execute next line:*

```
INSERT INTO `objects` (`sub_depts_id`, `objName`) VALUES (2, "obj1");
```

**must be the error because not unique data**

*after execute next line:*

```
INSERT INTO `objects` (`sub_depts_id`, `objName`) VALUES (3, "obj1");
```

**success**

Could you help me update the schema of the table, please?
I am using the latest version of MySQL. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: There's no way to specify that in the table schema, MySQL doesn't have any automatic check across tables like this. You could do it with triggers that check when you insert a record if the ID is already used in the other table. But there's no way to make `AUTO_INCREMENT` skip IDs that are used in the other table.

Comment: Culd you check your requirement?  
"relationship between tables objects and depts must be one-to-one"

Comment: .. Continue ..
"... relationship between tables objects and depts must be one-to-one ..."
Yet in your example you allow obj1 to belong to more than one department?
Also both of your examples would result in error due to UNIQUE objName.